# jquery multilevel menu with back button - multiple back button elements being created

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a mobile menu interaction

**How it should work:**

When clicking "Open" a ul element with two li items are shown.
When clicking on either of the li items, a nested ul is displayed and if any of the li items in it have children, a span to show "more" is also included in the markup.

When I click "more" I see the third level ul with li items, and a back button is created with jquery and appended to the third-level menu.

**The problem**

When I click through the first parent li, I get expected results. When I click the other parent li, and its children and then "back", I see multiple "back" elements are being created.

I can't put my finger on why. There is likely a flaw in my logic and I was hoping someone could help me spot it. Or suggest an approach to better debug this.

Thanks in advance. I can elaborate more if needed

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/left23/ktdsxk1d/

```
var toggle_expand = $('.toggle-expand');
var menu = $('#main-nav');
var expand_menu = $('.expand-sub');
var sub_menu = $('.main-menu--sub');
var first_level_item = $('#main-nav > .main-menu > li');
var second_level_menu = $('#main-nav > .main-menu > li > .main-menu--sub-1');
var second_level_item = $('#main-nav > .main-menu > li > .main-menu > li');
var third_level_menu = $('.main-menu--sub-2');

// Mobile Menu Show/Hide.
toggle_expand.on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('toggle-expand--open');
  menu.toggleClass('main-nav--open');

  if (!$(this).hasClass('toggle-expand--open')) {
    reset();
  }

});

// top level menu items

first_level_item.on('click', function(e) {

  first_level_item.not(this).each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).children(second_level_menu).removeClass('main-menu--sub-open');
  });

  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $(this).children('.main-menu--sub').toggleClass('main-menu--sub-open');

  expandMenu();

});


// second level menu items
function expandMenu() {

  expand_menu.on('click', function(e) {

    $(this).addClass('expand-sub--open');
    $(this).next(third_level_menu).addClass('main-menu--sub-open');
    $(this).closest(first_level_item).addClass('active');

    e.stopPropagation();

    backButton();

  });

}

// back button
function backButton() {

  var back_button_html = '<div class="back-button">Back</div>';

  // append element to bottom of list
  third_level_menu.append(back_button_html);

  var back_button = $('.back-button');

  back_button.on('click', function(e) {

    console.log('back');

    $(this).parent(third_level_menu).removeClass('main-menu--sub-open');
    $(this).parent(third_level_menu).prev(expand_menu).removeClass('expand-sub--open');

    $(this).parents('#main-nav > .main-menu > li').addClass('active');

    back_button.remove();

    e.stopPropagation();

  });

}


// reset to starting state
function reset() {
  console.log('reset');
  first_level_item.removeClass('active');
  sub_menu.removeClass('main-menu--sub-open');
  expand_menu.removeClass('expand-sub--open');
  $('.back-button').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reasons of this issue is because you create two buttons under `third_level_menu` at the same time and bind both buttons `click()` event. So if we click on `more` button and switch to another `first_level_item` and click `more` button again, then it would continuously create `back` button and bind a `click` event to all of the `back` buttons, including those buttons which have already binding a `click` event.

And when we switching between `first_level_item`, which would `expandMenu()` and having the same problem as I mentioned above.

So, before binding `click()` event, we could `off()` the original one to avoid firing same event multiple times. Also, select the right `back` button that going to be removed.

```
$('.back-button:visible');
```

and right `third_level_menu` to append new `back` button.

```
$('.main-menu--sub-2:visible');
```

```js
var toggle_expand = $('.toggle-expand');
var menu = $('#main-nav');
var expand_menu = $('.expand-sub');
var sub_menu = $('.main-menu--sub');
var first_level_item = $('#main-nav > .main-menu > li');
var second_level_menu = $('#main-nav > .main-menu > li > .main-menu--sub-1');
var second_level_item = $('#main-nav > .main-menu > li > .main-menu > li');
var third_level_menu = $('.main-menu--sub-2');

// Mobile Menu Show/Hide.
toggle_expand.on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('toggle-expand--open');
  menu.toggleClass('main-nav--open');

  if (!$(this).hasClass('toggle-expand--open')) {
    reset();
  }

});

// top level menu items

first_level_item.on('click', function(e) {

  first_level_item.not(this).each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).children(second_level_menu).removeClass('main-menu--sub-open');
  });

  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $(this).children('.main-menu--sub').toggleClass('main-menu--sub-open');

  expandMenu();

});


// second level menu items
function expandMenu() {

  expand_menu.off('click').on('click', function(e) {

    $(this).addClass('expand-sub--open');
    $(this).next(third_level_menu).addClass('main-menu--sub-open');
    $(this).closest(first_level_item).addClass('active');

    e.stopPropagation();

    backButton();

  });

}

// back button
function backButton() {

  var back_button_html = '<div class="back-button">Back</div>';

  // append element to bottom of list
  $('.main-menu--sub-2:visible').append(back_button_html);

  var back_button = $('.back-button:visible');

  back_button.on('click', function(e) {

    console.log('back');

    $(this).parent(third_level_menu).removeClass('main-menu--sub-open');
    $(this).parent(third_level_menu).prev(expand_menu).removeClass('expand-sub--open');

    $(this).parents('#main-nav > .main-menu > li').addClass('active');

    $(this).remove();
    
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

}


// reset to starting state
function reset() {
  console.log('reset');
  first_level_item.removeClass('active');
  // not sure if we want this! Consider a starting state
  sub_menu.removeClass('main-menu--sub-open');
  expand_menu.removeClass('expand-sub--open');
  $('.back-button').remove();
}
```

```css
.main-nav {
  display: none;
  width: 90%;
}

.main-nav--open {
  display: block;
}

.main-nav {
  z-index: 99;
}

.main-nav>ul.main-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.main-nav>ul.main-menu>li.main-menu__item {
  flex: 0 1 33%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: flex-start;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.main-nav>ul.main-menu>li.main-menu__item>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: padding 0.2s;
}

.main-nav>ul.main-menu>li.main-menu__item.active>a {
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
}

.main-nav>ul.main-menu>li.main-menu__item.active>.main-menu--sub-open {
  z-index: 20;
}

.main-nav>ul.main-menu>li.main-menu__item>ul.main-menu.main-menu--sub.main-menu--sub-1 {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  padding: 1rem 1rem 0;
  width: 50vw;
  top: 160px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.main-nav>ul.main-menu>li.main-menu__item>ul.main-menu.main-menu--sub.main-menu--sub-1.main-menu--sub-open {
  display: block;
}

.main-nav>ul.main-menu>li.main-menu__item>ul.main-menu.main-menu--sub.main-menu--sub-1>li.main-menu__item.main-menu__item--with-sub.main-menu__item--sub.main-menu__item--sub-1 {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.main-nav>ul.main-menu>li.main-menu__item>ul.main-menu.main-menu--sub.main-menu--sub-1>li.main-menu__item.main-menu__item--with-sub.main-menu__item--sub.main-menu__item--sub-1:first-child {
  border: 0 none;
}

.main-nav>ul.main-menu>li.main-menu__item>ul.main-menu.main-menu--sub.main-menu--sub-1>li.main-menu__item.main-menu__item--with-sub.main-menu__item--sub.main-menu__item--sub-1>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-nav>ul.main-menu>li.main-menu__item>ul.main-menu.main-menu--sub.main-menu--sub-1>li.main-menu__item.main-menu__item--with-sub.main-menu__item--sub.main-menu__item--sub-1>ul.main-menu.main-menu--sub.main-menu--sub-1.main-menu--sub-2 {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  padding: 1rem 1rem 0;
  width: 50vw;
  top: 160px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}

.main-nav>ul.main-menu>li.main-menu__item>ul.main-menu.main-menu--sub.main-menu--sub-1>li.main-menu__item.main-menu__item--with-sub.main-menu__item--sub.main-menu__item--sub-1>ul.main-menu.main-menu--sub.main-menu--sub-1.main-menu--sub-2.main-menu--sub-open {
  display: block;
}

.main-nav>ul.main-menu>li.main-menu__item>ul.main-menu.main-menu--sub.main-menu--sub-1>li.main-menu__item.main-menu__item--with-sub.main-menu__item--sub.main-menu__item--sub-1>ul.main-menu.main-menu--sub.main-menu--sub-1.main-menu--sub-2>li.main-menu__item.main-menu__item--with-sub.main-menu__item--sub.main-menu__item--sub-1.main-menu__item--sub-2 {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.main-nav>ul.main-menu>li.main-menu__item>ul.main-menu.main-menu--sub.main-menu--sub-1>li.main-menu__item.main-menu__item--with-sub.main-menu__item--sub.main-menu__item--sub-1>ul.main-menu.main-menu--sub.main-menu--sub-1.main-menu--sub-2>li.main-menu__item.main-menu__item--with-sub.main-menu__item--sub.main-menu__item--sub-1.main-menu__item--sub-2:first-child {
  border: 0 none;
}

.main-nav>ul.main-menu>li.main-menu__item>ul.main-menu.main-menu--sub.main-menu--sub-1>li.main-menu__item.main-menu__item--with-sub.main-menu__item--sub.main-menu__item--sub-1>ul.main-menu.main-menu--sub.main-menu--sub-1.main-menu--sub-2>li.main-menu__item.main-menu__item--with-sub.main-menu__item--sub.main-menu__item--sub-1.main-menu__item--sub-2>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.toggle-expand {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.toggle-expand--open {
  background-color: white;
}

.toggle-expand__open {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.toggle-expand--open .toggle-expand__open {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-expand__close {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.toggle-expand--open .toggle-expand__close {
  display: inline-block;
}

.back-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2rem;
  width: auto;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: red;
}

.expand-sub {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2rem;
  width: auto;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="toggle-expand" class="toggle-expand toggle-expand--open">
  <span class="toggle-expand__open">
    Close
    </span>
  <span class="toggle-expand__close">Click to open menu</span>
</a>

<nav id="main-nav" class="main-nav">
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li class="main-menu__item main-menu__item--with-sub">
      <a class="main-menu__link main-menu__link--with-sub" href="#">
      Item 1
    </a>
      <ul class="main-menu main-menu--sub main-menu--sub-1">
        <li class="main-menu__item main-menu__item--with-sub main-menu__item--sub main-menu__item--sub-1 main-menu__item--with-sub">
          <a class="main-menu__link main-menu__link--with-sub main-menu__link--sub main-menu__link--sub-1 main-menu__link--with-sub" href="#">
      Item 1 Child 1</a>
          <span class="expand-sub">more</span>
          <ul class="main-menu main-menu--sub main-menu--sub-1 main-menu--sub main-menu--sub-2">
            <li class="main-menu__item main-menu__item--with-sub main-menu__item--sub main-menu__item--sub-1 main-menu__item--with-sub main-menu__item--sub main-menu__item--sub-2">
              <a class="main-menu__link main-menu__link--with-sub main-menu__link--sub main-menu__link--sub-1 main-menu__link--with-sub main-menu__link--sub main-menu__link--sub-2" href="#">Item 1 Child 1 Grandchild 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="main-menu__item main-menu__item--with-sub main-menu__item--sub main-menu__item--sub-1 main-menu__item--with-sub main-menu__item--sub main-menu__item--sub-2">
              <a class="main-menu__link main-menu__link--with-sub main-menu__link--sub main-menu__link--sub-1 main-menu__link--with-sub main-menu__link--sub main-menu__link--sub-2" href="#">Item 1 Child 1 Grandchild 2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="main-menu__item main-menu__item--with-sub">
      <a class="main-menu__link main-menu__link--with-sub" href="#">
      Item 2
    </a>
      <ul class="main-menu main-menu--sub main-menu--sub-1">
        <li class="main-menu__item main-menu__item--with-sub main-menu__item--sub main-menu__item--sub-1 main-menu__item--with-sub">
          <a class="main-menu__link main-menu__link--with-sub main-menu__link--sub main-menu__link--sub-1 main-menu__link--with-sub" href="#">
      Item 2 Child 1</a>
          <span class="expand-sub">more</span>
          <ul class="main-menu main-menu--sub main-menu--sub-1 main-menu--sub main-menu--sub-2">
            <li class="main-menu__item main-menu__item--with-sub main-menu__item--sub main-menu__item--sub-1 main-menu__item--with-sub main-menu__item--sub main-menu__item--sub-2">
              <a class="main-menu__link main-menu__link--with-sub main-menu__link--sub main-menu__link--sub-1 main-menu__link--with-sub main-menu__link--sub main-menu__link--sub-2" href="#">Item 2 Child 1 Grandchild 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="main-menu__item main-menu__item--with-sub main-menu__item--sub main-menu__item--sub-1 main-menu__item--with-sub main-menu__item--sub main-menu__item--sub-2">
              <a class="main-menu__link main-menu__link--with-sub main-menu__link--sub main-menu__link--sub-1 main-menu__link--with-sub main-menu__link--sub main-menu__link--sub-2" href="#">Item 2 Child 1 Grandchild 2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>





  </ul>


</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks @Hikarunomemory, for the explanation and the code.

Edit: just saw your recent edit. I am trying again now :)